# Type 'inout UIButton' does not conform to protocol 'ReactiveCompatible'

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

```
passWordInputView.inputTextField.rx.controlEvent(.editingDidEnd)
        .bindTo(loginButton.rx.tap)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

when password edit done then login

but get error:
Type 'inout UIButton' does not conform to protocol 'ReactiveCompatible'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since RxSwift contains [the following line](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/0b66f666ba6955a51cba1ad530311b030fa4db9c/RxSwift/Reactive.swift#L74), you can be pretty sure that something else is giving the compiler trouble when you get this error for any NSObject subclass (anything in UIKit).

```
extension NSObject: ReactiveCompatible { }
```

---

In my experience this error happens when trying to use rx methods or operators incorrectly or if there is some syntactical error.

For example I got this error for a collectionView when trying to merge two streams like this

```
Observable.merge(collectionView.rx.streamOne, streamTwo)
```

But the correct way to merge the two streams is

```
Observable.of(collectionView.rx.streamOne, streamTwo).merge()
```

(Note looks like static Observable.merge was added in RxSwift 3.4)

---

#### In your case

You are trying to bind the stream from `inputTextField.rx.controlEvent(.editingDidEnd)` which is `Observable<Void>` to `loginButton.rx.tap` which is an ***Observable***, and not an ***Observer***. In english, `button.rx.tap` is meant to be observed, and not meant to observe.

You may instead do something like this

```
inputTextField.rx.controlEvent(.editingDidEnd)
    .subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] in
        self.inputTextField.userInteractionEnabled = false
        self.doLogin()
    }
```

You could also merge the streams from the button and the textField as described above :)